# Rad Studio 10.2.3: Driver/Connection Registry File dbxconnections.ini not found

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, dbexpress, rad-studio

I am facing problems to use Delphi with MySQL ... I have been trying for weeks to solve the error but without success

i Am using AppServ : Apache + PHP + MYSQL 5.7.17

Someone please help me

On click ConnectionName Properties:

Error: Driver/Connection Registry File 'C:\Users\ROG3R\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\dbExpress\19.0\dbxconnections.ini' not found.

There is no dbExpress folder in the directory

C:\Users\ROG3R\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio

Have you tried full installation on all users?
yes but problem continues

When you select true connect property:

DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9IHi.jpg

Comment: Have you tried to do a repair install or a complete reinstall of Delphi?

Comment: Please include the text of the error messages in your question, don't link to external picture hosters..

Comment: Clearly, the IDE cannot find the dbxconnections.ini file. Now why is that? Is the file where it is looking? Or is it looking somewhere where the file isn't?

Comment: @DelphiCoder:  Although posting images of code is not encouraged, for obvious reasons, I'm not sure there is as much of a problem with error messages especially when, as here, the message is shown in context.

Comment: Weeks?  Why didn't you just google the error message text?

Comment: When you can't see images, it doesn't matter if it's code or error.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz:  Err, but the substance of the error message is in the Q title anyway.  Just saying ...

Comment: @Martyn - Thanks for saying. In that case there's no point in posting the image at all..

Comment: Post edited....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error shows up, when you have installed Delphi only for your own user.
Uninstall it, but don't delete the registry keys at the end of the uninstall process or you will loose all your settings and you would have to reinstall 3rd party componets.
After that reinstall Delphi, but this time for all users!

[Source](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.install/xe5-dbxconnections.ini-missed-edit/1083066)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling with deleting the registry keys (make a backup before)?

Comment: Thanks, delete as registry keys solved the problem!!